Google auth refresh tokens expiring after a few days
We use the youtube API on behalf of our users, but after 7 days some users report having to re-authenticate and generate new refresh and access tokens.
Our app is in production mode, so we are confused as to what is causing this?
async function authenticateURL(scopes, referringUrl) {
    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: scopes.join(' '),
        prompt: 'consent',
        state: referringUrl
    });

    return authUrl;

}

const scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
];

Our solution at the moment is to email users and get them to re-authenticate. And we have tried changing up the scopes and toggling between test/production mode.
enter image description here
